# show error while fetch username

Tags: laravel, lumen

show error : Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\AdminLoginController::name()

```
 public function name($username) {
            $user = AdminLogin::find($username);
            return response()->json($user);
        }
```

AdminLoginController: Its a adminlogin controller code

```
class AdminLoginController extends Controller{

public function show(){

        $res ="Hello world!"; 

        return response()->json($res);
    }

     public function log() {

        $users = AdminLogin::all();

        return response()->json($users);
    }    
    public function name($username) {
    $user = AdminLogin::where('username',$username)->first();
    return response()->json($user);
    }
```

RouteLoginController: Its a adminlogin controller code :

```
<?php

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->version();
});

$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function ($app)
{
    $app->get('adminlogin', 'AdminLoginController@show'); //get single route
    $app->get('user', 'AdminLoginController@log'); //get single route
    $app->get('username', 'AdminLoginController@name'); //get single route
    $app->post('adminlogin', 'AdminLoginController@login'); //get single route

});
```

Error :

(1/1) ErrorException
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\AdminLoginController::name()

Comment: i think your calling a name method without argument

Comment: Your `name` method call is missing an argument. You have to pass argument to your method call.

Comment: show your name method calling part @krunal

Comment: Please show to complete code including route code and controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller method is taking the username param but the route binding is not passing one. Change your route

```
$app->get('username', 'AdminLoginController@name');
```

to

```
$app->get('user/{username}', 'AdminLoginController@name');
```

If you don't want to change your route, change your controller function signature to the below (as shown in the other answers), and make sure you are passing the 'username' as request param while invoking the url.

```
public function name(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $user = AdminLogin::where('username',$request->username)->first();
    return response()->json(['user' => $user]);
}
```

Comment: but I want username directly without passing username in paramter

Comment: How do you want your url to look like?

Comment: If you want to pass username in the url example.com/api/v1/user/Krunal, then use the route changes I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling this function using an ajax request and putting the name in the query string. In this case, the `name` parameter will not be sent as an attribute of the function but will be part of the request object.

You can solve this like so:

```
public function name(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $user = AdminLogin::find($request->username);
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
public function name($username) {
    $user = AdminLogin::where('username',$username)->first();
    return response()->json(['user' => $user]);
}
```

**OR**

```
public function name(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $user = AdminLogin::where('username',$request->username)->first();
    return response()->json(['user' => $user]);
}
```

Comment: @Krunal Please show your route and controller code.

Comment: @krunal Use 

public function name(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $user = AdminLogin::where('username',$request->username)->first();
    return response()->json($user);
}

Comment: which answer ??

Comment: @krunal use

return response()->json($user);

to

return response()->json(['user' => $user]);